# SqlDataReader.GetString and sqlnullvalueexception

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to C#. I was executing some select queries from database tables using System.Data.SqlClient classes. I got sqlnullvalueexception while executing some select query. On googling I come to know that if the value is null in the database, SqlDataReader.GetString (or it's variants) will throw sqlnullvalueexception.
What is the best coding practice for this?

```
if (!sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(n)) value = r.GetString(n);
```

Any better way of coding?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you don't want to repeat this a lot, just create a helper function, like this:

```
public static class DataReaderExtensions
{
    public static string GetStringOrNull(this IDataReader reader, int ordinal)
    {
        return reader.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? null : reader.GetString(ordinal);
    }

    public static string GetStringOrNull(this IDataReader reader, string columnName)
    {
        return reader.GetStringOrNull(reader.GetOrdinal(columnName));
    }
}
```

Which you can call like this:

```
value = reader.GetStringOrNull(n);
```

Comment: are you sure about the second method reader.IsDBNull(columnName)?  I think it only takes an ordinal.

Comment: @AlexanderN - I think you're right.  It should be `reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(columnName))`

Answer (score 14):

The code you posted is fine. You could also do something like that :

```
value = r[n] as string;
```

If the value in the database is null, `r[n]` will return DBNull.Value, and the cast to `string` will return `null`.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
value = reader.GetValue(n).ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

That really is the best way to go about it if you wish to avoid any exceptions.  You need to decide whether or not a null field represents an exceptional situation in your code - if it doesn't then use this method.  If it does then I would suggest that you either allow the exception to be thrown or catch the exception and wrap it in a more meaniful exception and throw that one.

But the main thing to know is that this is the standard way to retrieve values from a data reader when a null field does not represent an exceptional situation in the application domain.