# How to avoid NULL value in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I made a code that download values from table in DB. Some row values is null and I get this exception:

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: I dati hanno valore Null. Impossibile chiamare il metodo o la proprietà su valori Null.
>      in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetFieldValue(Int32 index, Boolean checkNull)
>      in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
>   this is my code for population:

```
while (rdr.Read())
            {
                MainWindow.AppWindow.Teams_DataGrid.Items.Add(new
                {
                    code = rdr.GetString(7),
                    name = rdr.GetString(6),
                    championship = rdr.GetString(5),
                    shortName = rdr.GetString(8),
                    squadMarketValue = rdr.GetString(9)
                });
            }
```

How I can insert the string NULL in datagrid when the values is NULL?

Comment: Please view [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222116/sqldatareader-getstring-and-sqlnullvalueexception)

Answer (score 0):

Either check your `rdr.GetString()`, return value, or use the default value if it's null:

```
if (String.NullOrEmpty(rdr.GetString(7)) ? "Null" : rdr.GetString(7);
//or
var v = rdr.GetString(7) ?? "some default value, null from what you've said";
```

and so on ?